# What does it mean to do a "hot casting" of a brick?

Tags: civil-engineering

I was talking to someone about brickmaking and he said doing a "hot casting" of a brick requires more energy and there are alternatives that use less energy. What does that mean?

Comment: So what have you researched so far? Did you google “brick making” or “hot casting bricks”? What were your results?

Comment: Videos on mold making. None of them describe what hot casting is.

Comment: See https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=cKj-X_QWrbwC&pg=PA16&lpg=PA16&dq=brick+hot+casting&source=bl&ots=Bt7Eul4Ppb&sig=m-i86BRyxW5o-qLbVKLegJ7tpSQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi6vPSStofcAhXFe8AKHf0uAnYQ6AEwDnoECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q=brick%20hot%20casting&f=false

Comment: @SolarMike: "You have either reached a page that is unavailable for viewing, or reached viewing limit for this book."

Comment: @SF. that link still works for me - perhaps you are not allowed access to UK links - either way I was pointing out to the OP that there are easily found resources available...

Comment: @SolarMike: They are not easily found when you don't know what exactly to look for. For goodness sake, one of first hits on Google for 'hot casting brick' I get Beauty Hot Casting - Pornhub.com No results found for "hot casting of brick" (with quotes.) Most of resources are for hot casting of other materials, using a brick kiln.

Comment: Yeah, I just want to know the definition of hot casting a brick. I found nothing on the internet.

Comment: @opaque_dragon  "I found nothing on the internet" <--  If I had a nickel for every time someone said that  and within 5 minutes I had 3 detailed sources googled up, I'd be able to retire.    Now, to start, perhaps you could specify what sort of material you are thinking of - clay, ceramic, metal, etc.

Comment: Concrete bricks.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: It seems you know something neither OP or me knows. Why don't you share, as a brief overview answer. All I knew of bricks is they are cast, or otherwise formed from cold clay or similar raw material, and then fired. Never heard of hot-casting them; their material has quite extreme melting temperature, and the cast would need to be made of carbon or tungsten or something similar, energy requirements would be obscene, and cooling them in a way that won't destroy them to thermal stresses would be tricky to say the least. So, how does that look like practically?

Comment: @SF. I only know that terms should be unambiguous when asking a question.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: So, it's ambiguity between what? If you mean material, could you present overview of materials bricks can be hot-cast of? You insist on making it an in-depth, detailed question. It's not. It's a very general, simple question that requires a simple answer. Which should be readily known to anyone knowledgeable on the subject, but as shown by the comments, is not easy to find for a layman.